# column-count !important is ignored by chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, multiple-columns

```
#main .inside .ce_text {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 31px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 31px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 31px;
}

#main .inside .ce_tabcontrol_pane .ce_text {
    -moz-column-count: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 0;
    column-count: 0;
}
```

the second rule should be more important than the first one imo. Although chrome renders 2 columns (!important also doesn't help).
But: Safari is doing everthing correct. Why?

Chrome 24

Safari 6.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS/column-count) `0` is no valid input for `column-count`.

> Is a strictly positive  describing the ideal number of columns into which the content of the element will be flowed. If the column-width is also set to a non-auto value, it merely indicates the maximum allowed number of columns.

I think, what you mean is more like this:

```
#main .inside .ce_tabcontrol_pane .ce_text {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ44q/1/)** working in Chrome26 as well as Firefox19.